# Specify job id in flink application mode app

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink newbie here with an operational question.

I've got a simple flink app running in application mode: it consumes from an unbounded kafka source, runs 2 operators with some simple logic & state, then outputs to a kafka sink. The checkpoints are configured to write to an S3 bucket, and I've got the deployment set up to just run as a simple kubernetes service (as far as I understand it, each application instance is going to be running both the JobManager and TaskManager logic). The job is starting from a plain vanilla `main()` method (i.e. not via the flink CLI) by calling `StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute()`.

In my local integration testing on my machine with an S3 simulator running as a sidecar, I've noticed that the checkpoints get stored at a path like `s3://my-bucket/my-checkpoint-dir/<job-id>/...` which makes sense. Since I'm going to be running my application as a kubernetes service with multiple application instances, I imagine that I'll be able to set up a combination of health checks & monitoring to make sure that there's always one JobManager present to keep the job going during a deployment.

Here's my question. I've noticed that when I stop & start the cluster on my local machine during development, it ends up starting a new job with a new job id and thus not resuming from any of the previously stored checkpoints. That's fine locally, but I can foresee possibilities where I might need to shut down ***all*** the instances of the app in production and bring them back up again (upgrading flink, some major migration, an unforeseen major issue, etc). In a scenario like this, is there a way I can write my application code to explicitly use a known stable job id when I bring the instances back up?

(Ideally I'd like to not take an extra dependency on an external zookeeper cluster for the JobManager, but I can do it if there's no other option.)

Answer (score 1):

One answer to this involves using savepoints rather than checkpoints for operational tasks. See the docs on [Upgrading Applications and Flink Versions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/upgrading/#restarting-streaming-applications) for details.

Another resource to consider is the [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/), which is set up to handle job lifecycle management, using savepoints.

And to answer your actual question: I don't believe there's any way to specify the job ID for Flink to use.